# VS Code: Filter file list by name only

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-filter

**When using VS CODE, how can I filter the file list by file names only?**

VS Code has a search function that searches the files shows the results, but it searches the content of the files. I only want to search and filter by file name, not the contents of the file.

Example. When search for "foo" I want to be shown a file list like this:

foo.js

foo.cs

foo.html

foobar.css

goodfood.txt

and ignores all files with the content that in has the word foo.

Answer (score 2):

For my purposes, I found that Ctrl-P provides the file filtering that I am looking for. It is separate from the search function that searches through both file names and file content.